# Printing random numbers to list

Tags: c, list, random, duplicates

My task is to generate random numbers in range from 50 to 80, if generated number is even add it to list of even numbers, if it is odd add it to list of odd numbers. Program should run till both lists are filled with 10 numbers. Duplicates in list are not allowed. This code prints 20 different numbers and it is storing duplicates in list. So I think problem is with count_odd, count_even and checking for duplicates but I can’t find solution to that. Also I have to print all generated numbers and also both lists in the end. Numbers in linked list should be in descending  order

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct list numbers;
typedef struct list* Pos;

int PrintRandom();
Pos CreateNew();
int PrintList(Pos);

struct list {
    int number;
    Pos next;
};

int PrintList(Pos P) {
    if (P == NULL)
        printf("Empty list.\n");
    while (P != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", P->number);
        P = P->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

Pos CreateNew() {
    Pos q = NULL;
    q = (Pos)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if (q == NULL) return NULL;
    q->next = NULL;
    return q;
}

int PrintRandom() {
    int x = 0, max = 80, min = 50;
    x = (rand() % (max - min + 1) + min);
    printf("Random number is : %d\n", x);
    
    return x;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    Pos even, odd, q = NULL;
    even = malloc(sizeof(numbers));
    odd = malloc(sizeof(numbers));
    even->next = odd->next = NULL;
    int count_even = 0, count_odd = 0, j;
    Pos head_p =even, head_n=odd;

    while (count_even < 10 & count_odd < 10) {
        j = PrintRandom();
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            q = CreateNew();
            if (q == NULL) return -1;
            q->number = j;
            while (even->next != NULL && even->next->number > q->number) {
                even = even->next;
            }
            if (even->number== q->number)
                free(q);
            else
                q->next = even->next;
            even->next = q;
            even =head_p;
            count_even++;
        }
        else {
            q = CreateNew();
            if (q == NULL) return -1;
            q->number = j;
            while (odd->next != NULL && odd->next->number > q->number) {
                odd = odd->next;
            }
            if (odd->number == q->number)
                free(q);
            else
                q->next = odd->next;
            odd->next = q;
            odd = head_n;
            count_odd++;
        }
    }

    printf("Even numbers in list are:\n");
    PrintList(head_p->next);
    printf("Odd numbers in list are:n");
    PrintList(head_n->next);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"Program should run till both lists are filled with 10 numbers.`" This sentence is unclear. What should happen if the odd list contains 10 numbers and the even list 9 numbers, and then another odd number is generated? Should it be added to the odd list, so that it contains 11 numbers? Or should that number be discarded?

Comment: If the odd list contains 10 numbers and the even list 9 numbers and then another odd number is generated it should be skipped since list of odd number is “full”

Comment: Are you required to use a linked list? If the limit is 10 numbers, then you could simply create two arrays of 10 elements, one for the odd numbers and one for the even numbers, and one additional variable specifying the number of valid numbers in each array (i.e. how full the array is). An array is easier to handle than a linked list.

Comment: Yes, I’m required to use linked list, I’m practicing for my data structures exam and this is example of last year exam

Comment: This is wrong: `while (count_even < 10 & count_odd < 10) {` The `&` operator is the bitwise-AND operator, but you want the logical-AND operator, which is `&&`.

Comment: Thanks, but it still prints duplicates to the list, any idea how to stop that?

Comment: Start with an array preset with the values 50 to 80. Pick one *index* at random, replace it with the topmost element, and reduce the element count.

Comment: Instead of generating random numbers that you hope will be good, I think it's easier to map 10 out of a bag of 16 and 10 out of a bag of 15, without replacement, to 50 to 80.

Comment: In the line `while (even->next != NULL && even->next->number > q->number) {`, what is the point of `even->next->number > q->number`? As far as I can tell, it only makes sense to compare for equality, but not whether one is larger than the other. Did you intend to write `even->next->number != q->number` instead?

Comment: I think I would generate 10 numbers in the range 0 through 15 (without duplicates) and for each such number E add the value (50+2*E) to the 'even numbers' list, then generate 10 numbers (without duplicate)s in the range 0 through 14 and for each such number O add the value (51+2*O) to the 'odd numbers' list. The most difficult part would be just avoiding duplicates.

Comment: With that line of code I wanted to print to the list in descending order. If list is empty (even->next == NULL) set q node as first element, if not find the first element smaller than q->number and place q before first smaller element. For example if list is filled with 8, 6, 2 and q->number = 4 final list should be 8, 6, 4, 2

Comment: With so many selections, I would think [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) would be an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several bugs:

---

### First bug:

The loop

`while (count_even < 10 & count_odd < 10) {`

will stop as soon as either `count_even` or `count_odd` reaches `10`. However, in your question, you stated that the loop should only stop when both have reached `10`.

Therefore, you should change that line to the following:

`while ( count_even < 10 || count_odd < 10 ) {`

Also, it is worth pointing out that `&` is the bitwise-AND operator. You probably intended to use the logical-AND operator, which is `&&`.

---

### Second bug:

In the comments section, you stated that if one of the lists is already full (has 10 elements), then all additional numbers that belong in that list should be discarded instead. However, your program does not contain any code to check for this. Instead, your program will keep adding new elements to the list, even if it already has 10 elements.

---

### Third bug:

The following code is wrong:

```
if (even->number== q->number)
    free(q);
else
    q->next = even->next;
even->next = q;
even =head_p;
count_even++;
```

First of all, you should change the expression

`even->number== q->number`

to:

`even->next->number== q->number`

However, since `even->next` may be null, you must test for that beforehand, so that the entire line would look like this:

`if ( even->next != NULL && even->next->number== q->number)`

Also, the lines

`even->next = q;`

and

`count_even++;`

should not be executed if the number already exists. Therefore, you should move these lines inside the `else` block. After performing these changes, your code should look like this:

```
if ( even->next != NULL && even->next->number== q->number)
{
    free(q);
}
else
{
    q->next = even->next;
    even->next = q;
    count_even++;
}
even =head_p;
```

The same changes should be performed on the code branch for the odd numbers.

---

### Fourth Bug:

There is a backslash character missing in the following line:

`printf("Odd numbers in list are:n");`

You should change it to:

`printf("Odd numbers in list are:\n");`

---

### Additional remarks:

There are two other things that I think could be improved in your code:

- The first element of the linked list is just a dummy node in which the `number` field is not initialized. You seem to be using this node for nothing else than holding the head pointer to the actual linked list.
- You have a lot of code duplication. Instead of using the same code for handling both even and odd numbers, you have separate, but very similar code for handling each case.

In the code below, I have rewritten most of your code to show you can see how I would solve this problem. Don't be surprised if you find it hard to understand, as I am using pointers to pointers, which can be hard for beginners to understand. As you can see, I am not using any dummy nodes, and I am also using the same code for handling both even and odd numbers. Only in two places of my code do I have different code for handling even and odd numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct list_node
{
    int number;
    struct list_node *next;
};

int PrintRandom();
int PrintList( struct list_node * );

int PrintList( struct list_node *p)
{
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Empty list.\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        while ( p != NULL )
        {
            printf( "%d\n", p->number );
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int PrintRandom() {
    int x = 0, max = 80, min = 50;
    x = (rand() % (max - min + 1) + min);
    printf("Random number is : %d\n", x);

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );

    struct list_node *head_even = NULL, *head_odd = NULL;
    int count_even = 0, count_odd = 0, random;
    bool is_even;

    while ( count_even < 10 || count_odd < 10 )
    {
        struct list_node **pp, *p, *q;

        //generate and print random number
        random = PrintRandom();

        //determine whether number is even or odd
        is_even = random % 2 == 0;

        //set pp to point to head pointer of the appropriate list
        //and check whether the appropriate list is already full
        if ( is_even )
        {
            if ( count_even >= 10 )
                continue;
            pp = &head_even;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( count_odd >= 10 )
                continue;
            pp = &head_odd;
        }

        for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while (1)
        {
            p = *pp;

            //if we reached the end of the list, break out of the loop
            if ( p == NULL )
                break;

            if ( p->number <= random )
            {
                if ( p->number == random )
                {
                    //discard number, because it already exists in list

                    //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                    //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                    //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                    goto next_outer_loop_iteration;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            pp = &p->next;
        }

        //allocate memory for new node
        q = malloc( sizeof *q );
        if ( q == NULL)
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "error allocating memory for new node!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //initialize new node
        q->number = random;
        q->next = p;

        //insert node into list
        *pp = q;

        //increment the appropriate counter
        if ( is_even )
            count_even++;
        else
            count_odd++;

    next_outer_loop_iteration:
        continue;
    }

    printf("Even numbers in list are:\n");
    PrintList( head_even );
    printf("Odd numbers in list are:\n");
    PrintList( head_odd );

    //NOTE: The memory of the linked lists is not being freed

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now it works fine, thanks! Only thing I added to your answer, since it still prints more than 10 numbers in even/odd list, I changed if ( j%2 == 0) to if (j%2 == 0 && count_even < 10) also before printing to the odd list I added if (count_odd < 10) do the rest.

Comment: @duje.je: Now that your code works, I have added my own solution to my answer. (I didn't want to give you the solution before you solved it yourself).

Comment: You did the lords work writing out this whole answer